# How to view source code of Secured browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

To automate a web application using selenium, the source code is needed to findElements to create xpaths. But when we press F12, we get nothing. But we have links in Front End. Please help...
The application runs only in IE...
If you need any other info, please let me know.

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: What do you see in the _HTML_ tab of _Development Tools_ when you press _F12_?

Comment: Its nothing. F12 is not working in that web application.

Comment: How about _View Source_?

Answer (score 1):

You can try driver.getPageSource() after you have loaded the page.
In debug mode - copy the value and use any of html viewer online for example https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester#